# Magento customer vs customer_collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

what's the difference between:

```
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
```

And

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
```

Or with product and `product_collection` (I think the difference will be the same, no?)

Answer (score 1):

In a normal install there is no difference. Both calls return the same thing.
But theoretically you can assign to the customer model a different collection resource model , not the default one.
I've never seen someone do that until now.

Comment: Don't want to edit your post ... but maybe this link could be added: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21154019/5703627